# Java: Apply Hamming Window to Audio File

Tags: java, function, window

I would like to apply the Hamming Window Function to an audio File.
[Window Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFjD9.png)

My Java Class so far:

```
public class SpeechRecognition {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // load File
    byte[] audioBytes = loadFile("hallo.wav");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(audioBytes));

    // preEmphasis
    audioBytes = preEmphasis(audioBytes);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(audioBytes));

    // windowing & overlap
}

// preEmphasis | s'N = sN - asN-1 | emph = 0.97
public static byte[] preEmphasis(byte[] input) {
    byte[] output = new byte[input.length];
    float emph = 0.97f;

    output[0] = input[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (byte) (input[i] - emph * input[i - 1]);
    }

    return output;
}

public static byte[] windowing(byte[] input) {

}

public static double[] calculateFFT(byte[] signal) {
    final int mNumberOfFFTPoints = 1024;
    double mMaxFFTSample;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int mPeakPos = 0;

    double temp;
    Complex[] y;
    Complex[] complexSignal = new Complex[mNumberOfFFTPoints];
    double[] absSignal = new double[mNumberOfFFTPoints / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfFFTPoints; i++) {
        temp = (double) ((signal[2 * i] & 0xFF) | (signal[2 * i + 1] << 8)) / 32768.0F;
        complexSignal[i] = new Complex(temp, 0.0);
    }

    y = FFT.fft(complexSignal); // --> Here I use FFT class

    mMaxFFTSample = 0.0;
    mPeakPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (mNumberOfFFTPoints / 2); i++) {
        absSignal[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y[i].re(), 2) + Math.pow(y[i].im(), 2));
        if (absSignal[i] > mMaxFFTSample) {
            mMaxFFTSample = absSignal[i];
            mPeakPos = i;
        }
    }

    return absSignal;

}

public static float melToFreq(float input) {
    return (float) (700 * (Math.pow(10, input / 2595) - 1));
}

public static float freqToMel(float input) {
    return (float) (2595 * Math.log10(1 + (input / 700)));
}

// load wav File
public static byte[] loadFile(String name) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int totalFramesRead = 0;
    File fileIn = new File(name);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
    int bytesPerFrame = audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
    if (bytesPerFrame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) {
        bytesPerFrame = 1;
    }
    int numBytes = 1024 * bytesPerFrame;
    byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    int numFramesRead = 0;
    while ((numBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(audioBytes)) != -1) {
        numFramesRead = numBytesRead / bytesPerFrame;
        totalFramesRead += numFramesRead;
    }

    return audioBytes;
}
}
```

I would like to know if I read the file correctly and how I can apply the function now to my byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the reading of the bytes as follows because the way you have it reads just one frame (if at all):

```
public static byte[] loadFile(String name) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int totalFramesRead = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    File fileIn = new File(name);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
    int bytesPerFrame = audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
    if (bytesPerFrame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) {
        bytesPerFrame = 1;
    }
    int numBytes = 1024 * bytesPerFrame;
    byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    int numFramesRead = 0;
    while ((numBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.length)) != -1) {
        outputSteam.wite(audioBytes, 0, numBytesRead);
    }
    byte[] bytesOut=outputStream.toByteArray();    
    return bytesOut;
}
```